# Why does my Javascript not work on objects added via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

So, I've got some JavaScript functions on my page to execute when certain objects change, which works fine.

On my page I can add more of these objects via an AJAX/post etc, which also works fine.

However, the JavaScript I have written will not work for these newly added objects *unless* I stick the JavaScript inside a `$(document).ajaxStop`.

I've fixed the problem by moving the code, but can someone explain to me why this is, I have no idea and am quite new to the whole process but my googling has not really brought me back an explanation (could be that I'm not googling the right terminology) and I'm wondering if I'm doing it the best way I should.

The specific example I had was:

```
$(".subTable").change(function(event){
    $myObj = $(event.target)
    var objID = $myObj.attr('name')
    var objClass =$myObj.attr('class')  
    var objVal = $myObj.val();

    $newObj = $myObj.closest('td').next('td').find('input[type = checkbox]')
    var checkedval = $newObj.is(":checked");

    if((objVal!= "") && (!checkedval)){
        $newObj.click();
    }
    if(objClass=="subField"){
        updateHiddenField(objID)    
    }

  });
```

This would work fine until I added new objects, then they would only work once I put them inside:

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function () {

});
```

Comment: can you show the code?

Comment: Which javascript code are you talking about? Be aware, e.g, handlers are bound to element already existing in DOM. You can still delegate event to closest static container

Comment: Sorry I didn't realise code would have helped so much in this instance as I thought the question was quite generic.  @fatman managed to guess my predicament right though (I wasn't aware of an "on" in javascript so will now refactor my code to use that) Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you did not post any code it's really hard to tell but i can guess that it is related to using [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) vs [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

1. `$('selector').click()` - that will only work on elements that are in the dom when you bind the event to them, i.e. it will not work on dynamically added elements unless you specifically bind the event to them after they were added (probably that is the reason why it works when you moved the code to ajaxStop)
2. `$('ul').on('click','li', function(){})` - this will work on dynamically added elements. Please note that the element you bind the `on` event must be in the dom when you bind it (i.e. in this case the 'ul' must be in the dom when you bind the event, but the 'li' can be dynamic.

Comment: Thanks your guess was spot on, in this specific example it was 'change' but I'm guessing that's the same as 'click' and so the same thing is required.  Thanks for the explanation I will go and update my code! :)

Comment: you are right, all the helper methods act the same.

Answer (score 1):

When ever you add a new element to page through js, those newly added element will not have the events attached previously. So you should attach the event as soon as you add the element to the page.

Also using jquery you can use .on to attach the events. This will attach events for newly added elements also.